# Fast recolor bitmap

Tags: java, android

I need to recolor bitmap, according to HashMap where the key is a source color and value is a target color.

I achieve results by iterating pixels:

```
public void recolor(Bitmap origBitmap, Bitmap newBitmap, Map<Integer, Integer> colorReplace) {
    for (x = 0; x < origBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < origBitmap.getHeight(); y++ {
            newBitmap.setPixel(x, y, colorReplace.get(origBitmap.getPixel(x, y)));
        }
    }
}
```

It seems perfect but works little slow even on an emulator running on overclocked i7 CPU. On real devices works very slow, sometimes unstable.

I searched some way to make it faster and more stable. I presume that it can be done via PorterDuffColorFilter or other ColorFilter, but don't understand how.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: see `Bitmap#getPixels` / `Bitmap#setPixels`

Comment: setPixel is the worst way to do that.  You'd even be better off getting the full pixel data array and mutating it directly.  But neither PorterDuff not ColorFilter will help you, neither is made to replace colros with arbitrary values in a HashMap.

Comment: And FYI your algorithm will crash if the value of a source pixel isn't in your map.  Not sure if the rest of your code prevents that, but figured you should be warned.

Comment: @GabeSechan HashMap contains all colors because generated by an iterating original (as I see getPixel much faster than setPixel) and in the emulator always works. Thanks, I will try to get pixels in an array

Comment: or you can switch to a "madman mode" and use [JNI AndroidBitmap_* API](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap) but i doubt it would much faster than `getPixels` / `setPixels`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice in comments! I find a solution that works fast enough (approximately 70 milliseconds instead 3500 in my particular case) and stable.

```
public void recolor(Bitmap origBitmap, Bitmap newBitmap, Map<Integer, Integer> colorReplace) {
    final width = origBitmap.getWidth();
    final height = origBitmap.getHeight();
    final int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    origBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    for (i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = colorReplace.get(pixels[i])
    }
    newBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width,0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: and replace `pixels[1]` with `pixels[i]`

Comment: @pskink yes, sure, strange typo when correcting formatting of example

Comment: btw tried jni and https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap or 70 ms is just good enough?

Comment: 70 ms is really cool for my needs. With this speed, it can be done without separate thread, but for some unknown reasons (maybe for very slow devices), I run it in a separate thread. :)